# Is there an algorithm help us to write each even number as sum of primes numbers?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

1) Is there an algorithm help us to  write each even number as sum of primes numbers :

for example :$4=2+2$

$8=3+5$

where : $3,5,2$ are primes

2) why we couldn't writing all odd numbers as sum of primes?

**Late Edit:** example look :$7=3+2+2$

I would be interest for any replies or any comments

Comment: Do you mean any number of prime number or two prime number?

Comment: @agha :i think the 2 cases are difficult

Comment: No, because you can write even number $n$ as sum of $\frac{n}{2}$ 2's, for example $10=2+2+2+2+2$ and odd number as sum of $\frac{n-1}{2}$ and 3, for example $9=3+2+2+2$.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't what you're looking for, but if you want to express a positive even number $n$ as a sum of primes, simply sum $2$ a total of $\frac n2$ times. For odd numbers $n>1,$ simply sum $3$ with a total of $\frac{n-3}2$ $2$s.

Comment: Rafik: When you change your question, almost an hour after first posting it, please *say so in your post*. Otherwise, it can render answers incomplete. Also note, rafik, that it's not much fun for answerers to to have to keep chasing a moving target. And I for one am not about to continue the chase.

Comment: @am why  : I see to delete the second question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Goldbach's conjecture that every even number greater than 2 is the sum of two primes.

Last year Harald Helfgott proved that every odd number greater than 5 is the sum of three primes.

For the last decade, Tomás Oliveira e Silva has run distributed calculations to verify the Goldbach conjecture into the quintillions.

I have no idea about the algorithms.

Comment: thank you very much for this accurate Answer , then my problem still about the existence of algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Re: Original question, under the assumption that we are speaking of the sum of **two** primes...

Your first question is indeed [Golbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) (addressing your comment below). It is an open question (as to *whether* ***every*** even number greater than $2$ can be written as the sum of **two** primes).

For your second question.

All prime numbers, with the exception of $2$, is odd. And odd + odd = even.

Some odd numbers can be written as the sum of **two** primes: $2+3 = 5$, $\;2+5 = 7, \;2+7 = 9,\;2+11 = 13,  2+ 17 = 19$.

But in general, this won't work for all odd numbers.

For example, $11 = 1+10 = 2+9 = 3+8 = 4+7 = 5+6$. All fail to be sums of two prime numbers. $17 = 1+16 = 2+15=3+14 = 4+13 = 5+12=6+11 = 7+10 = 8+9$. Again, $17$ (an odd number) fails to be the sum of two primes.

Adding two odd numbers (and so adding two odd primes) will always result in an even number.

Comment: The question is about finding primes to sum to a given even number, not finding the parity of the sum of two primes.

Comment: @Charles : "why we couldn't writing all odd numbers as sum of primes?" Because... Odd numbers can never be the sum of two odd primes...and all primes except $2$ are odd. So *except for the odd numbers that result from adding *the only even prime* with another prime ( $2 + \text{odd prime}$,) all sums of primes excluding two as a summand, will be even.

Comment: @charles , yes this is what i would be interest, i'm seeking in general for algorithm about finding primes to sum

Comment: I think my first question is open question and Goldback conjecture

Comment: Yes, @rafik. I'm addressing your second question.

Comment: @ am why: see the second question , i'm not said to write each  odd number as sum of 2 primes , but i said as sum of primes numbers , then it's mean we could write it as sum of 3 or 4or 5..primes

Comment: You didn't specify two primes in your first question either. The question is rather trivial, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm is simple: Given an even number n, iterate through the small primes (eventually up to n/2, though you're unlikely to need to go that far). For each $p$ check if $n-p$ is prime. If so you're done.

The expected work is about $0.5\log n$ primality tests with about $0.3\log^2n$ in the extreme cases. Of course it's not even known that you can find a solution, let alone by the $O(log^2n)$-th prime.

Comment: thank you for Algorithm , but my question ABOUT the existence of Algorithm in general, i think if algorithm existed then yield to prove The GOLDBACH'S CONJECTURE

Comment: The algorithm described above does "exist in general", you've got what you're asking for

Comment: @ john Fernley ,since algorithm existed , why the conjecture not proved unti now ?

Comment: @Charles your method is a brute force method only suitable for computational devices, but the OP asks for a direct humanly calculatable method

Comment: @rafik the conjecture is an open problem because we do not know that this algorithm will find the required decomposition for every even number. It always works to find a decomposition, but only if one exists